# Greencard application: Civil Documents: Photographs

Tags: usa, greencard

After submitting my DS-260 with the NVC, I have to upload "Civil Documents". One of the requested items is **PHOTOGRAPHS**. I assume I have to upload a portrait of myself?

Is there any exact format/criteria I need to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the requirements of the DS-260. However, usually the requirements for portraits are the same as passport pictures. So just take pictures as if you would be applying for a passport and submit to them.